¿Por qué debemos escribir «hindúes» en vez de «hindues»?
En este artículo publicado en el «Diccionario panhispánico de dudas» se menciona:

El plural preferido en la lengua culta es hindúes.

Quiero saber las reglas ortografícas específicas que indican que la palabra «hindúes» debe llevar tilde en la u. En otras palabras ¿Cómo uno puede determinar por su cuenta que la forma correcta es «hindúes» y no «hindues»?
Busqué un poco de información en Internet para responder esa pregunta. Encontré este artículo publicado en la «Ortografía de la lengua española» en la que se menciona:

En español, constituyen hiatos desde el punto de vista articulatorio las siguientes combinaciones vocálicas:
a) Una vocal cerrada tónica (i, u) seguida o precedida de una vocal abierta átona (a, e, o) : po.dí.a, rí.o, des.ví.e, pú.a, pun.tú.e, flú.or, ra.íz, re.ír, e.go.ís.ta, ta.húr, fe.ú.cho, fi.no.ú.grio.

En la palabra «hindúes», u es una vocal cerrada tónica seguida de la vocal abierta e (creo que u es tónica porque en mi cabeza recordé a varias personas poner más enfásis en la sílaba «dú» que «es» al decir «hindúes»). De acuerdo a ese artículo, «hindúes» tiene hiato, entonces la división silábica de la palabra «hindúes» es hin.dú.es.
Encontré este artículo publicado en la «Ortografía de la lengua española» en la que se menciona:

a) Las palabras que contienen un hiato formado por una vocal cerrada tónica seguida o precedida por una vocal abierta llevan siempre tilde en la vocal cerrada, con independencia de las reglas generales de acentuación. Por eso se acentúan gráficamente palabras como serías, sabíais, desvíen, mío, cacatúa, actúe, búhos, caídas, reído, oído, transeúnte o finoúgrio, a pesar de ser llanas terminadas en -n, -s o vocal; lo mismo ocurre en raíz, reír, oír, laúd o tahúr, que llevan asimismo tilde aun siendo agudas terminadas en consonante distinta de n o s.

Anteriormente, yo había determinado que la división silábica es hin.dú.es, entonces «hindúes» es una palabra llana. Teniendo en cuenta el artículo, a pesar de ser llana terminada en -s tiene independencia de las reglas generales de acentuación, por lo que debe ser tildada en la vocal cerrada.
¿Mi razonamiento es correcto? Si no es así ¿En qué parte estoy mal?

Creo que ninguno de los ejemplos de tu pregunta está relacionado con hindúes. Esta viene del plural de hindú, que ya va acentuado. Deberías cotejarla con palabras de estructura similar, como menú, cebú, ñandú, ragú, etc.

Tu conclusión es correcta. Se escribe:
Hindúes
Para completar alguna información que falta en tu análisis:
Plural
El por qué la U es tónica, viene del artículo plural del Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas, que en su sección 2.1 dice:

La vocal tónica es la misma en el singular y en el plural, salvo en las palabras espécimen, régimen y carácter, en las que el acento cambia de lugar en el plural: especímenes, regímenes y caracteres  [karaktéres].

Al ser tónica la U en Hindú, es tónica en Hindúes.
Hiato
Luego, la palabra efectivamente tiene hiato (en lugar de diptongo), por lo que las vocales se pronuncian en sílabas distintas.
hin • dú • es
La sección 2.2.2.3 de la Ortografía de la lengua es llamada hiatos y dice:

Los hiatos son secuencias de dos vocales que se pronuncian en sílabas distintas. En español, constituyen hiatos desde el punto de vista articulatorio las siguientes combinaciones vocálicas:
a) Una vocal cerrada tónica (/i/, /u/) seguida o precedida de una vocal abierta átona (/a/, /e/, /o/)

Tílde
Del por qué se tilda en la U, la respuesta está en el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas, en el artículo tilde, en la sección 2.3.2. Acentuación gráfica de las palabras con hiato:

a) Las palabras con hiato formado por una vocal cerrada tónica y una vocal abierta átona, o por una vocal abierta átona y una cerrada tónica, siempre llevan tilde sobre la vocal cerrada, con independencia de lo que establecen las reglas generales de acentuación: armonía, grúa, insinúe, dúo, río, hematíe, laúd, caída, raíz, feúcho, cafeína, egoísmo, oír.

El resaltado es mío.

Coincido con Danielillo. También me llamó la atención porque como hablante nativo uno tiene naturalizado este tema de agregar -es a la vocal final si está acentuada.
"Las palabras que terminan en vocal tónica están sufriendo una evolución en la lengua para regularizar su plural, de forma que en lugar de -es cada vez es más frecuente -s. El proceso ya se puede considerar completado cuando es -á (de bajá, antes bajaes y hoy bajás) u -ó (de rondó, antes rondoes y hoy rondós)[1]. pero se sigue vacilando cuando las vocales finales son -í y -ú, con clara tendencia a la regularización.

La siguiente lista da la forma que recogen diversas obras. Como regla general, las Academias de la Lengua en la NGLE (pp. 132-134) actualmente aceptan la formación con -s aunque prefieren las variantes con -es en la lengua culta. En el DPD (entrada 'PLURAL', apartado 1c) se indicaba este mismo criterio:"

https://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Plural_con_-í_y_-ú

Es correcto. Lo de revisar si la palabra termina en -n, -s o vocal + la acentuación prosódica para determinar si lleva o no lleva tilde es lo que vendría a llamarse las ‘reglas generales de acentuación’. Se cumplen en el 90 por ciento de los casos y son las de menor prioridad. Por encima, hay diversas excepciones a estas reglas generales que, como toda excepción, tiene mayor precedencia.
Una analogía similar es lo de la prioridad de paso en la calle: si no se tiene más información, en general el que tiene prioridad en un cruce es el que va por el carril derecho (al menos en Argentina), pero después hay diversas excepciones que sobreescriben la regla general: el que va por la ruta tiene prioridad respecto del que quiere entrar desde la ciudad, el que va en subida tiene prioridad por sobre el que va en bajada, el que va por la rotonda tiene prioridad por sobre el que quiere entrar, etc.; en estos casos no aplica lo de la regla de la mano derecha.
La excepción en tu ejemplo viene a ser ésta: si la palabra tiene una combinación entre una vocal cerrada y una abierta, o entre dos vocales cerradas, y además lleva hiato, entonces se pone la tilde siempre para aclarar. Por lo tanto, debe ser ‘hindúes’ (hin-DU-es), y no ‘hindues’ (HIN-dues) pues quedaría el diptongo en la ‘ue’. A partir de esta excepción, se deducen todos los demás ejemplos que son parte de esta excepción: quería, había, baúl, Raúl, cafeína, dúo, etc.
POSDATA
Bueno, en realidad mentí cuando dije que los hiatos siempre llevan tilde. Lo que ocurre es que la pronunciación admite muchos grises, a diferencia de lo que ocurre en la escritura. De esta forma, hay un grupo de palabras relativamente grande que supuestamente se puede pronunciar tanto con hiato como con diptongo. En los buenos viejos tiempos ambas grafías eran válidas; pero desde 1999 la casta proscribió la tilde y ahora se exije tratarlas como diptongos en la escritura—por supuesto que no entiendo el por qué, cuando jamás escuché un diptongo en este grupo de palabras. Ejemplos de estas palabras son:

Verbos en -uir: construir (cons-TRUIR o cons-tru-IR), huir (HUIR o hu-IR), incluir (in-CLUIR o in-clu-IR), etc. (lo de huir con diptongo es realmente raro para mí xd)
Verbos en -iais o -ieis, como liais (LIAIS o li-AIS)
Monosílabos en -ion: pion (PION o pi-ON), guion (GUION o gui-ON)
truhan (TRUHAN o tru-HAN)

Última y me dejo de joder, pero podría ser útil: el fenómeno inverso también puede ocurrir. Es decir, nunca entendía por qué la palabra ‘cráneo’ lleva tilde si es bisílaba y grave. Pero claro: en teoría, al ser dos vocales abiertas no puede llevar diptongo. Por lo que la separación en sílabas ‘correcta’ es cra-ne-o, y de ahí se sigue que debe pronunciarse CRA-ne-o y no cra-NE-o. Sin embargo, la ‘e’ y la ‘o’ muchas veces se asimilan y por eso uno tiene la sensación de escuchar sólo dos sílabas en lugar de tres (CRA-neo).
